# How to point package.json

Tags: npm, package.json

I'm trying to install this https://github.com/VadimDez/ngx-order-pipe using the command

`npm install  ngx-order-pipe --save`

but I get a

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\<directoryName>\package.json'
```

when I clearly have it in

```
C:\Users\<directoryName>\Source\Repos\July17\DDE\Web\package.json
```

so my question is, how do I tell/point NPM to my existing package.json file?

Comment: Change to the `C:\Users\<directoryName>\Source\Repos\July17\DDE\Web\` directory first?

Comment: Woops, did that and now I'm getting a `SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
` error

Comment: That's not an error, it's just telling you it's skipping an optional Mac-only package.

Answer (score 0):

ceejayoz's answer is what I needed since I didn't know I could use CMD lines for Package Manager Console.

So for the sake of answering, just in case, I did a

```
cd C:\Users\<directoryName>\Source\Repos\July17\DDE\Web
```

on the Package Manager Console.